# Parse JSON and show data in Angular

Tags: json, angularjs, node.js, express

I have a trouble with displaying JSON data in Angular. I successfully send data from backend to frontend (Angular), but I cannot display them.

I tried to simulate a similar situation on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29y61wtg/2/), although I already have prepared data from backend [image: following format]

get/send data -> Backend side:

```
//push data to Redis
var messages= JSON.stringify(
    [
        {
            "name": "Msg1",
            "desc": "desc Msg1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Msg2",
            "desc": "desc Msg2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Msg3",
            "desc": "desc Msg3"
        },
        {
            "name": "Msg4",
            "desc": "desc Msg4"
        }
    ]);
    redisClient.lpush('list', messages, function (err, response) {
        console.log(response);
    });

//get from redis and send to frontend
app.get('/messages', function(req, res){
    // Query your redis dataset here
    redisClient.lrange('list', 0, -1, function(err, messages) {
        console.log(messages);
       // Handle errors if they occur
       if(err) res.status(500).end();
       // You could send a string
       res.send(messages);
       // or json
       // res.json({ data: reply.toString() });
    });
});
```

get data -> frontend (Angular)

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        'use strict';

        getFromServer();
        function getFromServer(){
          $http.get('/messages')
               .success(function(res){
                   $scope.messages= res;
                   console.log(res);
               });
        }
    }])
```

HTML part with ng-repeat directive:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in messages">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{item.name}}</h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">{{item.desc}}</p>
    <div>
</div>
```

Would anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Try using $scope.messages = JSON.parse(res);

Comment: Can you share your entire HTML (index.html or whatever it happens to be)?

Comment: Your response appears to be an array of strings by the looks of the console output.  @Dodekeract has the right answer, you just have to do res[0] as well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As far as I can see, you're storing your Object as JSON, but you never parse it. Therefore using

```
$scope.messages = JSON.parse(res);
```

instead of

```
$scope.messages = res;
```

should fix your problem.

Here is a working JSFiddle version of yours: https://jsfiddle.net/29y61wtg/5/

Note, that this doesn't include a $http call, if you're still having problems after using $http, tell me in the comments.

Comment: Thank you guys. I have another question and I'm not sure should I open a new question... Does anyone has experience with combination of socketio and redis? I would like to listen on the server for new data (for example message 5) and emit it to the client. I already include angular-socket-io on the client, but I don't have idea how to connect data from redis in socket.

Comment: You should open a new question for that. I'm probably the only user who will see this comment for some time.