# Parsing from a JSON and show in angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have two JSON format data. How can i parse them and show in angular? I am really confused how to proceed. Also in the second data the plan_id refers to the "plan" data. How can i make that small lookup object which will look up the "plan" using the plan_id. Below are the json files and my index

```
{  
   "plans":[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "code":"NEXT_DAY_500gm",
         "name":"Next Day less than 500gm",
         "cost":55,
         "duration":24,
         "min_weight":0,
         "max_weight":500,
         "COD":1,
         "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
         "updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
      },
      {  
         "id":2,
         "code":"NEXT_DAY_500gm_1kg",
         "name":"Next Day 500gm to 1kg",
         "cost":70,
         "duration":24,
         "min_weight":501,
         "max_weight":1000,
         "COD":1,
         "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
         "updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
      },
      {  
         "id":3,
         "code":"NEXT_DAY_1kg_2kg",
         "name":"Next Day 1kg to 2kg",
         "cost":95,
         "duration":24,
         "min_weight":1001,
         "max_weight":2000,
         "COD":1,
         "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
         "updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
      },
      {  
         "id":4,
         "code":"SAME_DAY_500gm",
         "name":"Same Day less than 500gm",
         "cost":95,
         "duration":8,
         "min_weight":0,
         "max_weight":500,
         "COD":1,
         "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
         "updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
      },
      {  
         "id":5,
         "code":"SAME_DAY_500gm_1kg",
         "name":"Same Day 500gm to 1kg",
         "cost":130,
         "duration":8,
         "min_weight":501,
         "max_weight":1000,
         "COD":1,
         "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
         "updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
      },
      {  
         "id":6,
         "code":"SAME_DAY_1kg_2kg",
         "name":"Same Day 1kg to 2kg",
         "cost":165,
         "duration":8,
         "min_weight":1001,
         "max_weight":2000,
         "COD":1,
         "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
         "updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
      }
   ]
}



[{"id":23,"sender_id":3,"courier_id":0,"deliverer_id":0,"status":"PENDING","consignment_id":"55C0A999","sender_name":"asdasdas d","cost":"40","package_description":"asdasdasd","sender_address":"asdasdasd","sender_longitude":"","sender_latitude":"","sender_number":null,"receiver_address":"adasdasd","receiver_name":"Shifat Adnan","receiver_number":"01713206053","receiver_longitude":"","receiver_latitude":"","current_longitude":"","current_latitude":"","deliverer":null,"recipient_pays":0,"instructions":"2332323","payment_status":null,"cod":0,"recipient_zone_id":2,"plan_id":2,"store_id":null,"storeproduct_id":null,"created_at":"2015-08-04 12:01:29"},{"id":28,"sender_id":5,"courier_id":0,"deliverer_id":0,"status":"COMPLETED","consignment_id":"10F317","sender_name":"bleh","cost":"398","package_description":"Business Order","sender_address":"bleh","sender_longitude":"bleh","sender_latitude":"bleh","sender_number":"bleh","receiver_address":"kjakdjlsdjlaksdjl","receiver_name":"Nigga","receiver_number":"010203001","receiver_longitude":"","receiver_latitude":"","current_longitude":"bleh","current_latitude":"bleh","deliverer":null,"recipient_pays":0,"instructions":"jslklsdflkj","payment_status":null,"cod":0,"recipient_zone_id":null,"plan_id":4,"store_id":null,"storeproduct_id":null,"created_at":"2015-10-04 09:36:23"},{"id":34,"sender_id":5,"courier_id":0,"deliverer_id":0,"status":"PENDING","consignment_id":"137F24","sender_name":"bleh","cost":"3223","package_description":"Business Order","sender_address":"bleh","sender_longitude":"bleh","sender_latitude":"bleh","sender_number":"bleh","receiver_address":"kasdlkaskd asldka","receiver_name":"FAAskl","receiver_number":"199102909","receiver_longitude":"","receiver_latitude":"","current_longitude":"bleh","current_latitude":"bleh","deliverer":null,"recipient_pays":0,"instructions":"dsdsdf","payment_status":null,"cod":0,"recipient_zone_id":2,"plan_id":3,"store_id":null,"storeproduct_id":null,"created_at":"2015-10-06 07:58:28"},{"id":35,"sender_id":5,"courier_id":0,"deliverer_id":0,"status":"COMPLETED","consignment_id":"13C476","sender_name":"bleh","cost":"3310","package_description":"Business Order","sender_address":"bleh","sender_longitude":"bleh","sender_latitude":"bleh","sender_number":"bleh","receiver_address":"sdfs dfasdfasdfasdf","receiver_name":"sfasd","receiver_number":"224","receiver_longitude":"","receiver_latitude":"","current_longitude":"bleh","current_latitude":"bleh","deliverer":null,"recipient_pays":0,"instructions":"dasdasd","payment_status":null,"cod":0,"recipient_zone_id":2,"plan_id":1,"store_id":1,"storeproduct_id":1,"created_at":"2015-10-06 12:54:14"},{"id":36,"sender_id":5,"courier_id":0,"deliverer_id":0,"status":"COMPLETED","consignment_id":"13C4B3","sender_name":"bleh","cost":"330","package_description":"Business Order","sender_address":"bleh","sender_longitude":"bleh","sender_latitude":"bleh","sender_number":"bleh","receiver_address":"sdfs dfasdfasdfasdf","receiver_name":"Some full name","receiver_number":"224","receiver_longitude":"","receiver_latitude":"","current_longitude":"bleh","current_latitude":"bleh","deliverer":null,"recipient_pays":0,"instructions":"dasdasd","payment_status":null,"cod":0,"recipient_zone_id":3,"plan_id":4,"store_id":1,"storeproduct_id":2,"created_at":"2015-10-06 12:55:15”}]
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Reports </title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="reportApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <table>

    </table>

</body>
```

I dont know what to do next. How to parse and show the json? Please help or give any leads.

Comment: A great lead is go through the [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) on the documentation site. Also do some studying on working with javascript arrays and objects. To be quite honest what you are asking is `how do I use angular` and to use it you need a basic understanding of arrays

Comment: [Googling your question title](https://www.google.com/search?q=Parsing+from+a+JSON+and+show+in+angular) finds [Parse JSON and show data in Angular](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31415270/1168892), which should give you some hints. Please consider googling your problems before posting them here.

Comment: @charlietfl The official tutorial is actually pretty old (sadly), I would recommend the [codeschool.com](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js) tutorial, as it contains most of modern angular best practices.

Comment: I have seen that question @dominik. But actually i dont need any http request. I have my json data. Just want to parse them and show them.

Comment: @charlietfl the practices are old. It just teaches a lot of bad practices which we then frequently see here because the official tutorial seems like a good place to go for new people, when it is in fact not

Comment: @hhs the answer clearly contains what you need. There the json comes from an http request, you already have it. In both ways you have to bind it to the `$scope` (or `this` if you use `ControllerAs`), then use it in your template (e.g. with `ng-repeat`).

Comment: say the json data var name is "data". then i do $scope.jsonData= JSON.parse(data);

?

Answer (score 0):

alocate your json object to some scope object variable
Note: Please take care of the terminators (;) wherever it requires.
Hope this may give you an idea how to do.

```
$scope.jsonScopeObject={  
   "plans":[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "code":"NEXT_DAY_500gm",
         "name":"Next Day less than 500gm",
         "cost":55,
         "duration":24,
         "min_weight":0,
         "max_weight":500,
         "COD":1,
         "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
         "updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
      },
      {  
         "id":2,
         "code":"NEXT_DAY_500gm_1kg",
         "name":"Next Day 500gm to 1kg",
         "cost":70,
         "duration":24,
         "min_weight":501,
         "max_weight":1000,
         "COD":1,
         "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
         "updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
      },
      {  
         "id":3,
         "code":"NEXT_DAY_1kg_2kg",
         "name":"Next Day 1kg to 2kg",
         "cost":95,
         "duration":24,
         "min_weight":1001,
         "max_weight":2000,
         "COD":1,
         "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
         "updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
      },
      {  
         "id":4,
         "code":"SAME_DAY_500gm",
         "name":"Same Day less than 500gm",
         "cost":95,
         "duration":8,
         "min_weight":0,
         "max_weight":500,
         "COD":1,
         "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
         "updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
      },
      {  
         "id":5,
         "code":"SAME_DAY_500gm_1kg",
         "name":"Same Day 500gm to 1kg",
         "cost":130,
         "duration":8,
         "min_weight":501,
         "max_weight":1000,
         "COD":1,
         "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
         "updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
      },
      {  
         "id":6,
         "code":"SAME_DAY_1kg_2kg",
         "name":"Same Day 1kg to 2kg",
         "cost":165,
         "duration":8,
         "min_weight":1001,
         "max_weight":2000,
         "COD":1,
         "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
         "updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
      }
   ]
}

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Pathao Reports </title>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body ng-app="reportApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
        <table>
             <th>head1</th>
             <th>head2</th>


        </table>
        <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="data in jsonScopeObject.plans">
                 <td>{{data.id}}</td>
                 <td>{{data.code}}</td>

              <tr>
        </tbody>



</body>
```