# while using ng-repeat tag with json data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

When I get the data in JSON format and try to print it using `ng-repeat` tag, I get the error

> `ng-dupes error`

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="emp in empArr">
      <td>{{emp.empcode}}</td>
      <td>{{emp.empName}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Also the AngularJS function which is retrieving the json format :

```
$scope.Show = function() {

$http.get("get_oracle_data.jsp?sqlStr=SELECT empcode,empname from emp")
    .then(function(response) {
       $scope.empArr = response.data;
});
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON and show data in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415270/parse-json-and-show-data-in-angular)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `trackBy` to avoid duplication error.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="emp in empArr track by $index">
    <td>{{emp.empcode}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.empName}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: post your json arr

Comment: This is the JSON arr i am getting as a response :

Comment: [{"empcode":"12","empName":"nishant"},
{"empcode":"28","empName":"abc"},
{"empcode":"65","empName":"dsf"},
{"empcode":"13","empName":"dszc"}]

Comment: track by index should work. @Dinu12. and this JSON will work even without `track by`. possibly you are making mistake at someplace else

Comment: thanks @sachin the data was coming with some extra character.

Answer (score 0):

You may try for this:

**track by $index** is used for remove duplicacy from array list:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="emp in empArr track by $index">
    <td>{{emp.empcode}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.empName}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can check the similar example here in this fiddle

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/angsar/n8e312wf/)

```
      <div ng-app='t' ng-controller='test'>
            <div ng-repeat='x in DATA'>
                <p>
                    <label>Title: </label> {{x.complaint_title}}
                </p>
            </div>
    </div>

    (function(){

        var app = angular.module('t', []);

        app.controller('test', 
          [
              '$scope', 
              function($scope)                            
              {
                $scope.DATA = [
                  {
                    "complaint_id": "1",
                    "complaint_title": "blah",
                    "complaint_desc": "gdga",               
                    "incident_date": "2015-02-28"
                  },
                  {
                    "complaint_id": "2",
                    "complaint_title": "gbsdsg",
                    "complaint_desc": "asadf",               
                    "incident_date": "2015-02-27"
                  }

                ];

                }
          ]);//controller

})();//closure
```

Comment: you can check now